# Session and login in telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've made a telegram bot. Unfortunately, when two users have connected to the bot and send a message that will be saved into database, their message mixed. What I need here is how to make chat session on different user while communicating to the bot.

Also I want to make a user login in telegram bot.

Comment: you've tagged two independent libraries that both provide a wrapper for the bot api - which on are you using? please romve the tag for the one that you're not using

Comment: @CallMeStag python-telegram-bot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I avoid using global variables when writing a Telegram bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72146233/how-do-i-avoid-using-global-variables-when-writing-a-telegram-bot)