# Separate each message from each user in python telegram bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I want to make a telegram bot that can handle multiple chats from multiple users without being mixed up when each message is stored in the database.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it.  Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I avoid using global variables when writing a Telegram bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72146233/how-do-i-avoid-using-global-variables-when-writing-a-telegram-bot)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna store the user data, use user_id as the primary key. And use the User object to retrieve all other data

```
update.message.from_user.id
```

And store data in an Exel sheet instead of Mysql databases. It's sometimes hard to host a telegram bot with a MySQL database. The hosting cost will be so expensive.