# How to do a multiple choice menu with inline queries in python-telegram-bot (theory)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I want to create a multiple choice menu using `InlineKeyboardMarkup` where the user can select multiple things at once and then press another button to save the info continue with the conversation, like a checkbox form.

Here's the logic that I imagined, where a while loop continues to update a `temp` if `query.data` continues to not be `"continue"`, as you can see.

```
async def select_subjects(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> str:
        temp = {}
        query = update.callback_query
    
        while query.data != "continue":
    
            await query.answer()
    
            if query.data in temp:
                temp[query.data] = False
            else:
                temp[query.data] = True
    
            query = update.callback_query

        return "next"
```

The problem is that if I try to then click some buttons before the `"continue"` one it gives this error:

```
telegram.error.BadRequest: Query is too old and response timeout expired or query id is invalid
```

And `temp` remains empty. Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get several inputs in one command in telegram bot api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142791/how-to-get-several-inputs-in-one-command-in-telegram-bot-api)

Comment: Unfortunately not, because what I need is a sort of menu in which multiple options can be selected and toggled at once, as if the InlineKeyboardButtons where some sort of switches. Then, when the user presses "continue", it saves the query data of the toggled ones in a dict or a list.

Comment: you can you as ConversationHandler for that. stay in the same state until the "continue" button is pressed and update the buttons according to the users selection.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that! I'll try to do it this way and eventually post the answer to this question with the solution.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do what you suggested, and it almost works for my need. Unfortunately I say almost because the only factor that blocks me is that I need to save the previous state of the variable to keep track of the buttons that the user had pressed before, to create something like a checkbox list, and calling the function another time from the beginning doesn't let me do this. That's why I tried to use the while loop.

Comment: If you'd like to have more details I can give you the permission to the repository so you can see the code by yourself.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72146233

Comment: Wonderful! This works! I'll make the answer with the solution to this problem asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so thanks also to the help of [CallMeStag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10606962/callmestag) I have come to a solution to this problem, and it involves using the `context.user_data` feature of `python-telegram-bot` as it is shown below.
This is the function to display the options (or subjects in this case) in the first place

```
async def display_subjects(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> str:

    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()

    # Fuction that returns a simple example of a dict 
    # {"Maths": False, "Science": False, "Art": False}
    subject_list = find_subjects() 

    for i in subject_list:
        # Every subject in the dict is now put into the context.user_data with 
        # the False forced value
        context.user_data[i] = False

    await query.edit_message_text(SUBJECT_LIST, reply_markup=keyboard(subject_list))

    return "select_subjects"
```

This is then the function that manages the updating of the `user_data`.

```
async def select_subjects(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> str or int:
    query = update.callback_query

    await query.answer()

    if query.data != "continue":

        if not context.user_data[query.data]:
            context.user_data[query.data] = True
        elif context.user_data[query.data]:
            context.user_data[query.data] = False

        subjects_list = context.user_data

        await query.edit_message_reply_markup(keyboard(subjects_list))
        return "select_subjects"
```